# Include a link to the Code of Conduct in the FAQ for Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, code-of-conduct

Earlier I posted in a chat room for the first time so I figured I should read the relevant [FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise myself with how it works.

One of the questions is **Do I have to be nice?**  I figured that the answer to this question provides a good opportunity to remind users that the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) also applies when posting to chat rooms.

Comment: Reasonable request; the chat FAQ badly needs some love. FWIW, there *is* a link to the CoC in the pop-up that you see when you first join chat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/widCx.png